# String concatenation performance: + vs StringBuilder

Tags: java, jvm, jit

I was checking out [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java) , the top answer of which says there's "no performance difference whatsoever" between `+` and `StringBuilder.append()` because the former will be turned into the latter by JVM.
However per my benchmark, the `+` way is always about ~20% faster than the `StringBuilder` way (I'm on Java17, running Intel core i7):

```java
    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class BenchState {
        private String a = "A";
        private String b = "B";
        private String c = "C";
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void bmStringConcat(final BenchState state, final Blackhole blackhole) {
        String a = state.a;
        String b = state.b;
        String c = state.c;

        final String s = "{a:" + a + ", b:" + b + ", c: " + c + "}";
        blackhole.consume(s);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void bmStringBuilder(final BenchState state, final Blackhole blackhole) {
        String a = state.a;
        String b = state.b;
        String c = state.c;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final String s = sb.append("{a:").append(a)
                .append(", b:").append(b)
                .append(", c:").append(c)
                .append("}")
                .toString();
        blackhole.consume(s);
    }
```

Is it because the "+" version "is converted to `invokedynamic` call" as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43175128/12008421) .
Or there are more reasons?

Comment: Since you already found out that the answer from 2009 is outdated, yes, it’s very likely that the `invokedynamic` performs better, as that was one of the goals when introducing it. Make sure not to use the Eclipse compiler for comparing these variants, as it doesn’t support the `invokedynamic` yet. Or, verify the compiled code with `javap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @Holger's advice, I checked the bytecode for following code:

```java
public class StringBM {
    public String toStringPlus(String a) {
        return "{a:" + a + ", b:" + ", c: " + "}";
    }

    public String toStringBuilder(String a) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        return sb.append("{a:").append(a)
                .append(", b:")
                .append(", c:")
                .append("}")
                .toString();
    }
}
```

For `toStringPlus`, I get

```
  public java.lang.String toStringPlus(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_1
         1: invokedynamic #7,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:makeConcatWithConstants:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
         6: areturn
```

for `toStringBuilder`:

```
public java.lang.String toStringBuilder(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=3, args_size=2
         0: new           #11                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
         3: dup
         4: bipush        100
         6: invokespecial #13                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(I)V
         9: astore_2
        10: aload_2
        11: ldc           #16                 // String {a:
        13: invokevirtual #18                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        16: aload_1
        17: invokevirtual #18                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        20: ldc           #22                 // String , b:
        22: invokevirtual #18                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        25: ldc           #24                 // String , c:
        27: invokevirtual #18                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        30: ldc           #26                 // String }
        32: invokevirtual #18                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        35: invokevirtual #28                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        38: areturn
```

The `+` version simply invokes dynamic function `makeConcatWithConstants`.
Whereas the `StringBuilder` version has to do it the 'honest' way.
I guess we can see why is `+` faster now.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is correct, I have been doing some benchmarking in a project I'm involved with and have found that the `StringBuilder` method is still faster. I am using Java 17, I think it is important to size the `StringBuilder` to the size of the `String` expected. I would say the tests given are invalid.  i.e. `toStringBuilder` uses a 100 character `StringBuilder`, I make it that only a 13 size one is required (or 15 in the question). I agree, the `StringConcatFactory` has made things better than before, but believe there is still a place for `StringBuilder`.